# Cómo eliminar por id de un array que está dentro de otro en laravel

Tags: laravel, array, laravel-livewire

estoy haciendo una tabla livewire y ahora estoy en la sección de eliminar filas, para ello estoy obteniendo el id del item en cuestion, también tengo un array de toda la tabla

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Mr. Peyton Bradtke"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Savanna Lesch DDS"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "Dr. Lester Runolfsdottir"
  ]
]
```

si el ID obtenido fuera "1", cómo lo puedo eliminar de ese array? que es el perteneciente a "Savanna Lesch DDS"

lo único que quiero es eliminarlo del array, esta es mi función

```
public function delete($itemId)
{
  $itemsToDelete = $this->addItems;
    foreach ($itemsToDelete as $item)
    {
        if ($item['id'] == $itemId){

        }
    }
}
```

con esto logro ya interceptar el item en cuestion a eliminar, pero no sé cómo eliminarlo del array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logré hacerlo, primero encontré el método para quitar el ítem y empecé a hacer el foreach con un index para saber la posición de qué item borrar haciendo unset

```
public function delete($itemId)
{
    $itemsToDelete = $this->addItems;
    foreach ($itemsToDelete as $index => $item)
    {
        if ($item['id'] == $itemId){
            unset ($itemsToDelete[$index]);
        }
    }
    $this->resetValues();
    $this->addItemsToTable($itemsToDelete);
}
```

luego hice una función resetValues que me deja la tabla en blanco para poder añadir nuevamente los ítems sin el item eliminiado con la función de addItemsToTable

```
public function resetValues()
{
    $this->reset(['addItems']);
}

public function addItemsToTable($items)
{
    $this->addItems = $items;
}
```